# System of Differential Equations: Accelerating Point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, parametrization

> At $t=0$, a point starts at $(10,10)$ with a velocity of $20$ units per second in the positive $x$ direction. It also has a constant acceleration of $5$ units per second squared towards to origin at all times. What is its parametric equation?

First let me say that I am very unexperienced when it comes to differential equations, and I have no idea how to even approach this one.

To solve this problem, I started by saying that, if both $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$,
$$x''=5\cos\arctan\frac{y}{x}=\frac{5x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$y''=5\sin\arctan\frac{y}{x}=\frac{5y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Furthermore, because of the starting velocity, when $x''$ is integrated, the constant will end up being $20$. And when $x'$ and $y'$ are integrated, due to the starting position of the point, their constants will both be $10$. However, I don't know how to get to that point... I only know how to integrate *single* differential equations, and only simple ones at that. Can anybody explain to me if and how one can go about solving this problem?

Be warned: I made up this problem and I have no idea if it has a neat solution. If it can't be done and I am wasting my time, just tell me and explain why.

Comment: Since the acceleration is always directed toward the origin, this might be easier to solve in polar coordinates.

Comment: @amd Ooh, good idea... thanks! I'll try it, and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, the equations of movement are:

$$\begin{cases}
 \ddot r-r\dot\theta=-5\\
 \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d(r^2\dot\theta)}{dt}=0\implies r^2\dot\theta=L_\theta
\end{cases}$$

$$\ddot r-L_\theta/r=-5$$

It has not a simple solution... Elliptical integrals are needed.

[what would a planetary orbit look like if gravity had constant magnitude?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345571/what-would-a-planetary-orbit-look-like-if-gravity-had-constant-magnitude)

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian of a particle subjected to the constant acceleration towards the origin written in plane polar is
$$\mathcal{L}(r, \varphi, \dot{\varphi}, \dot{r})=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^{2}+r^{2}\dot{\varphi}^{2})+\alpha{r}$$
Where $\alpha$ is the magnitude of the acceleration. $\varphi$ is a cyclic variable, the conserved angular momentum is
$$L_{\varphi}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{\varphi}}=r^{2}\dot{\varphi}$$
So, $\dot{\varphi}=\frac{L_{\varphi}}{r^{2}}$, and the lagrnagian becomes
$$\mathcal{L}(r, \dot{r})=\frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^{2}+\frac{L_{\varphi}^{2}}{r^{2}}+\alpha{r}$$
The First integral is
$$E=\dot{r}\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{\dot{r}}}-\mathcal{L}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^{2}-\frac{L_{\varphi}^{2}}{r^{2}}-\alpha{r}$$
Thus
$$\dot{r}=\pm\sqrt{2E+\frac{2L_{\varphi}^{2}}{r^{2}}+2\alpha{r}}$$
or
$$t+c=\pm\int\frac{dr}{\sqrt{2E+\frac{2L_{\varphi}^{2}}{r^{2}}+2\alpha{r}}}$$
From this integral (if you manage to do it, via some elliptic functions e.g.), you can find $r(t)$ by inversion, the other parametric equation, for $\varphi$ is obtained by
$$\varphi+\varphi_{0}=\int\frac{L_{\varphi}}{r^{2}(t)}dt$$
The constants $\varphi_{0}$, $L_{\varphi}$, $E$ and $t_{0}$ are all found from the initial datum E.g. in your sepecific problem $\varphi_{0}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $t_{0}=0$. As the angular momentum is an integral of motion it is equal to the value it has initially at all times. $L_{\varphi}=r_{0}^{2}\dot{\varphi}_{0}$. $r_{0}^{2}=x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2}=200$. The initial velocity in the $x$ diraction is
$$\dot{x}=\dot{r}_{0}\cos{\varphi_{0}}-r_{0}\sin{\varphi_{0}}\dot{\varphi_{0}}=20$$ and $$\dot{y}_{0}=\dot{r}_{0}\sin{\varphi_{0}}+r_{0}\cos{\varphi_{0}}\dot{\varphi_{0}}=0$$
So,
$$\dot{\varphi}_{0}=-\frac{1}{10}$$
And finally $L_{\varphi}=-20$

Comment: The one you've written is incorrect mate, check it out!